# liferay plugin for eclipse version 4.3(kepler)

Tags: eclipse, liferay, liferay-6, update-site

I want to install liferay plugin in my eclipse version 4.3.

Is there any liferay-IDE update-site available for it?

my liferay version is liferay-portal-tomcat-6.1.2-ce-ga3

note:due to use liferay6.1 I needed to install java6 and remove java8 so I can not install newer versions of eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downloaded update-site 1.6.2 from https://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20IDE/ and it did work!

Answer (score 0):

1. In [Eclipse Marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org) search for [liferay](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/liferay)
2. Click on a search result
3. Click on the download icon (below the *Install* button)
4. Copy the update site URL, e. g. of the *Tern Eclipse IDE* (available also for *Kepler*): http://oss.opensagres.fr/tern.repository/1.2.0/

Note, you can install different Java versions, a new one to run the latest Eclipse IDE and Java 6 for your target application (see: *Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs*).

Comment: I appreciate for your help and tips but I didn't find liferay IDE for kepler eclipse in the Marketplace.
There was liferay IDE for laster versions of eclipse.